# Are Automatic Snapshots on Gcloud platform safe?

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine, gcloud, snapshot

I created a method to do some snapshots of my instances weekly, and for reasons of non-pollution I'm deleting a few snapshots to keep just one week. I read on gcloud guide to take care :

> Caution: If a snapshot of a regional permanent disk fails, you must
>   capture a clean snapshot before you delete that disk. This security
>   measure prevents accidental deletion of source data in case of backup
>   failure.

but as my method is automatic I will not see if an error appears. How risky is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the deletion of a persistent disk will look for [the status of all its snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/snapshots#Snapshot.FIELDS.status), and if any is not in a `READY` state, the deletion will fail.

You can simulate this kind of check by running the following command:

```
gcloud compute snapshots list --filter='sourceDisk:<SOURCE_DISK> AND -status:READY'
```

If this command returns any snapshot, the deletion will not be possible until you remove the failed snapshot.

Programatically, you can get the snapshots for a disk and verify their status is `READY` before proceeding with the deletion of the disk.

Regarding the snapshot deletion, before deleting the previous one, you can always verify the current snapshot is successful. Ideally, you should verify the snapshot was successful after running it, and retry if it failed.